Is there a way to document multipart form data with id ‘com.epages.restdocs-api-spec’ version “0.18.2” library?
I’m currently working on a Spring Boot project and I’m using the com.epages.restdocs-api-spec library version “0.18.2” to generate API documentation. However, I am having trouble documenting endpoints that consume multipart/form-data.
Here is a sample of my code:
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<EraseAreaRequestDto.Response> home(
        @ModelAttribute @Validated RequestDto dto
) {
    log.info("original filename: {}", dto.getOriginalImageFile().getOriginalFilename());
    log.info("masking filename: {}", dto.getMaskingImageFile().getOriginalFilename());
    log.info("original url: {}", dto.getOriginalImageUrl());
    log.info("masking url: {}", dto.getMaskingImageUrl());
    log.info("test1: {}", dto.getRequest3().getTest1());
    log.info("test2: {}", dto.getRequest3().getTest2());

    var response = new EraseAreaRequestDto.Response();
    response.setOriginalFilename(dto.getOriginalImageFile().getOriginalFilename());
    response.setMaskingFilename(dto.getMaskingImageFile().getOriginalFilename());
    response.setOriginalImageUrl(dto.getOriginalImageUrl());
    response.setMaskingImageUrl(dto.getMaskingImageUrl());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}


@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RequestDto {

    private MultipartFile originalImageFile;

    private MultipartFile maskingImageFile;

    private String originalImageUrl;

    private String maskingImageUrl;
}


@Test
public void documentMultipart() throws Exception {
            Part part = new MockPart("originalImageFile", "originalImageFile", new byte[10], MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
            Part part2 = new MockPart("maskingImageFile", "maskingImageFile", new byte[10], MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
            Part originalImageUrlPart = new MockPart("originalImageUrl", null, "originalImageUrl".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            Part maskingImageUrlPart = new MockPart("maskingImageUrl", null, "maskingImageUrl".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

            return mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.multipart(API_ERASE_AREA)
                    .part(part, part2, originalImageUrlPart, maskingImageUrlPart, part3)
                    .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
                    .characterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.originalFilename").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.maskingFilename").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.originalImageUrl").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.maskingImageUrl").exists())
                .andDo(document(
                        "{Identifier}",
                        resource(
                                ResourceSnippetParameters.builder()
                                        .summary("Summary")
                                        .description("description")
                                        .requestSchema(schema("RequestDto"))
                                        .formParameters(
                                                parameterWithName("originalImageUrl").description("adsf").optional().type(SimpleType.STRING),
                                                parameterWithName("maskingImageUrl").description("asdf").optional(),
                                                parameterWithName("originalImageFile").description("asdf").optional(),
                                                parameterWithName("maskingImageFile").description("asdf").optional()
                                        )
                                        .responseSchema(schema("EraseAreaRequestDto.Response"))
// skip...                                        .responseFields() 
                                        .tags("tag")
                                        .build())
                ));
}

Here is my build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.10.2'
    id 'com.epages.restdocs-api-spec' version "0.18.2"
}

ext {
    springShellVersion = "3.3.0"
    host = 'localhost:8888'
    apiUrl = '/'
}

group = 'com.asd'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-starter'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    // restdoc
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation "com.epages:restdocs-api-spec-mockmvc:0.18.2"
    testImplementation 'com.epages:restdocs-api-spec-restassured:0.18.2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-restassured'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-dependencies:$springShellVersion"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task copyYaml {
    logger.info("copyYaml -> ${project.buildDir}/resources/main/public/docs")

    copy {
        from "build/api-spec"
        into "${project.buildDir}/resources/main/static/docs"
    }
}

openapi3 {
    delete "build/api-spec"
    delete "build/generated-snippets"
    server = apiUrl
    title = 'test'
    description = "test test"
    tagDescriptionsPropertiesFile = 'src/docs/tag-descriptions.yaml'
    version = '0.1.0'
    format = 'yaml'
}

openapi {
    delete "build/api-spec"
    delete "build/generated-snippets"
    host = 'localhost:8888'
    title = 'test'
    description = "test test"
    tagDescriptionsPropertiesFile = 'src/docs/tag-descriptions.yaml'
    version = '0.1.0'
    format = 'yaml'
}


Additionally, here is the generated openapi3.yaml file created by the epages-restdocs library:
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: test
  description: test test
  version: 0.1.0
servers:
- url: /
tags: []
paths:
  /api/sample:
    post:
      tags:
      - "tag"      
      summary: summary
      description: description
      operationId: {idenifier}
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "200"          
          content:
            application/json;charset=UTF-8:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/RequestDto.Response'              
              examples:
                identifier:
                  value: "{\"originalFilename\":\"originalImageFile\",\"maskingFilename\"\                    :\"maskingImageFile\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"originalImageUrl\"\                    ,\"maskingImageUrl\":\"maskingImageUrl\",\"list\":null,\"array\"\                    :null}"

I want to document multipart/form-data using OpenAPI 3 with the epages-restdocs library. If that’s not possible, I’m okay with using OpenAPI 1. However, I want to ensure that when an object is included in the multipart request, all of the object’s fields are documented, just like they are with a request body.
